# How to Create ACL (Access Control List) in Azure When VIP Address is Changing From One Deployment to Another One?

Tags: azure, acl

I have azure cloud service (lets call it ACS) that uses another service on a seperate VM (lets call it ASVM). The azure cloud service (ACS) public virtual ip (vip) address is changing from one deployment to another deployment.  The VIP of the second service (ASVM) does not change.

I want to create ACL (Access Control List) on ASVM that will limit the connections to only connections comming from ACS.

How do I do it?  Do I need to configure ACS that VIP is not changing and is static.  I know that I can provide a range for ACL.  However VIPs of ACS seem to be a little unpredictable.

Thanks for help.

Learner.For.Ever

Comment: just to add: Azure Cloud Service (ACS) hosts web role.

Comment: Is it possible this type of traffic can use private IP instead of using public interface of the ASVM? You can still apply Azure NSG on the private interface

Comment: The service on ASVM is exposed using http.  So I am not sure if it can use private IP.

Comment: Probly make ACS static is the best bet, won't cost much. You can find all [Azure IP here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653). I don't think white list them is an option.

Comment: Thanks Kai.  I don't think that ACL rules will work as - I believe - a user can create up to 50 ACL rules and I see that there are more IP addresses used in my datacenter.  Thanks Kai for your help.  As I am a newbie here I did not earn yet point to mark it as an answer so thanks again.

Comment: Would anyone else have other suggestions?  Playing devils advacate.... :)

Comment: No worries. I do have another work around but I don't think fit you best. Assuming your ASVM is live on an Azure VLAN, you can open a point-to-site VPN between your webapps(ACS) and VLAN, then your traffic can go thru the VPN tunnel with static private IP. ACL on endpoints won't apply to private traffic. There is a cost associated with VPN gateway and it's harder to manage. Unless you have a serious concern over the internet route or you have complicated traffic, I don't think this would adjust the effort.

Comment: Thanks Kai.  I considered VPN after doing some research.  However I do not think that setting up VPN would be justified in my scenario.  Anyway thanks for additional idea! Learner.For.Ever